# Train Accuracy increases, Train loss is stable, Validation loss Increases, Validation Accuracy is low and increases

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, training-data, loss

My neural network trainign in pytorch is getting very wierd.

I am training a **known** dataset that came splitted into train and validation.
I'm shuffeling the data during training and do data augmentation on the fly.

I have those results:

Train accuracy start at **80%** and increases [image]

Train loss decreases and stays stable [image]

Validation accuracy start at **30%** but increases slowly [image]

Validation loss increases [image]

I have the following graphs to show:

[image]

1. How can you explain that the validation loss increases and the validation accuracy increases?
2. How can be such a big difference of accuracy between validation and training sets?  90% and 40%?

**Update:**

I balanced the data set.
It is binary classification. It now has now 1700 examples from class 1, 1200 examples from class 2. Total 600 for validation and 2300 for training.
I still see similar behavior:

[image]

**Can it be becuase I froze the weights in part of the network?

**Can it be becuase the hyperparametrs like lr?

Comment: Binary classification or more classes?

Comment: Binary classification

Comment: And I guess imbalanced, right?

Comment: They are about balanced (3000 vs 1200)

Comment: This is 2.5 to 1, so not "about balanced".

Comment: What is the solution? more data augmenting the second class?

Comment: Difficult to say w/o the data. Experiment is king. For starters, I would increase the size of val set, to be "sure" that the metrics are reliable and not spurious due to small sample size.

Comment: @desertnaut I updated the dataset. I still see similar behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:
I had different data augmentation for training set and validation set. Matching them also increased the validation accuracy!

Answer (score 0):

If the training set is very large in comparison to the validation set, you are more likely to overfit and learn the training data, which would make generalizing the model very difficult. I see your training accuracy is at 0.98 and your validation accuracy increases at a very slow rate, which would imply that you have overfit your training data.

Try reducing the number of samples in your training set to improve how well your model generalizes to unseen data.

Comment: My training data indeed bigger than the validation. about 5000 training and 200 validation. But why big training size induce overfitting? low number of samples incur overfitting!

Comment: @BestR the issue is not so much in the big training set, but in the too-small validation one. Keep in mind that, for all these *statistics* (loss, accuracy etc) to be valid, a large-enough underlying dataset is implicitly assumed, otherwise the results can be spurious and not actually representative

Comment: If you have 5200 samples in total, you should use a 60:40 or 70:30 split for training:validation

Comment: The dataset came this way. I will try balancing and report back

Comment: @kynnem I updated the results. I still see similar behavior.

Comment: Try changing the batch size or modifying the network structure and see what works to improve your validation metrics

Comment: @kynnem My network is densenet that I train only the classifier layer. The rest is freezed. I cant change batch size its 4 and due to memory its the limit.

Comment: Are you limited by memory on your computer? If so, you could try training on a Google Colab notebook to make use of their GPU with 12GB RAM

Comment: My GPU memory is 12GB, and the network on image size 512 and batch 4 almost capture it all.
I dont think batch size will help here. When I unfreeze the weights I see normal training behavior, but the final results are worse than the results with freezed training

Comment: 512 is rather a large image size. Could you try using patches of image size 256 or 128 to reduce the load on your hardware? Example code here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1bTbbAyUQHMTCQ7nR3nqjWMnRAXa3K5-j

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer your 2nd question first. High accuracy on training data and low accuracy on val/test data indicates the model might not generalize well to infer real cases. That is what the validation process is all about. You need to finetune or even rebuild your model.
With regard to the first question, val loss might not necessarily correspond to the val accuracy. The model makes the prediction based on its model, and loss function calculates the difference between probablities of matrix and the target if you are using CrossEntropy function.